# MYSQL сравнение timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица chats, а так же таблица members. Я пытаюсь получить новые чаты.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  chat.members AS m
  JOIN chat.chats AS c 
WHERE m.chatid = c.id  AND m.userid = ?i
```

И получаю массив:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21
        [userid] => 1
        [chatid] => 21
        [lastvisit] => 
        [display] => 1
        [lastupdate] => 2018-02-07 15:23:06
    )
```

Но дело в том, что как только я добавляю в запрос  `AND m.lastvisit < c.lastupdate` то есть условие, что нужно сделать выборку только там, где визит пользователя был раньше, чем произошло обновление чата, мне возвращается пустой массив, выборка не происходит.

Я не могу понять почему, так как элементарно в полученном прежде массиве, поле `lastvisit` пусто (пользователь ещё не посещал чат), а поле `lastupdate` имеет значение, и следовательно проверка `AND m.lastvisit < c.lastupdate` должна сработать.

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Не должна. `lastvisit` имеет значение `NULL`. А все операции (в том числе и сравнение) с `NULL` дают `NULL`  (который интерпретируется как FALSE). Кроме, собственно, непосредственной проверки `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL`

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужен такой запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM
  chat.members AS m
  JOIN chat.chats AS c 
WHERE
  m.chatid = c.id AND
  m.userid = ? AND
  (m.lastvisit < c.lastupdate OR m.lastvisit IS NULL)
```